# Docker & Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, docker, spring-boot, localhost

Всем привет, в java я новичок, есть приложение на Spring Boot, поставлено на контейнере Docker. При запуске Томкат занимает 8080 порт, и Докер тоже висит на нем же. Но почему-то достучаться до локалхоста не могу, Swagger не отвечает, хотя вчера все работало. Вообще это нормально что и Томкат и Докер на одном порту или они мешают друг другу запуститься? Спасибо всем заранее.
docker ps выдает
docker ps

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
2d8153c99567        appname-postgres-image   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:5433->5432/tcp             appname-postgres
bb6b241edcf3        registry:2                     "/entrypoint.sh /etc…"   37 hours ago        Up 2 minutes        5000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   registry
```

Boт содержимое db.gradle файла для сборки контейнера Докер

```
task startDB(group: 'application', description: 'Starts the postgres container.') {
    doLast {
        exec { commandLine 'echo', 'Starting PostgreSQL container' }
        exec { commandLine './docker/db/start.sh', '--port', '5433', '--name', 'appname-postgres' }
    }
}

task restartDB(group: 'application', description: 'Restarts the PostgreSQL container.') {
    doLast {
        exec { commandLine 'echo', 'Restarting PostgreSQL container' }
        exec { commandLine './docker/db/restart.sh', '--port', '5433', '--name', 'appname-postgres' }
    }
}

task stopDB(group: 'application', description: 'Stops the PostgreSQL container.') {
    doLast {
        exec { commandLine 'echo', 'Removing PostgreSQL container' }
        exec { commandLine './docker/common/stop.sh', '--name', 'appname-postgres' }
    }
}

task restartIntegrationDB(group: 'verification', description: 'Restarts the PostgreSQL integration container.') {
    doLast {
        exec { commandLine 'echo', 'Restarting PostgreSQL container' }
        exec { commandLine './docker/db/restart.sh', '--port', '5434', '--name', 'appname-postgres-integration' }
    }
}

task stopIntegrationDB(group: 'verification', description: 'Stops the PostgreSQL integration container.') {
    doLast {
        exec { commandLine 'echo', 'Removing PostgreSQL container' }
        exec { commandLine './docker/common/stop.sh', '--name', 'appname-postgres-integration' }
    }
}
```

Но я теперь сомневаюсь что это связано с Докером, так как я попробовала запустить другое приложение на SpringBoot, которое вообще с контейнером никак не связано, в IDE пишет что Томкат стартовал на хосте 8080, а на деле в браузере ничего не открывается

Также содержимое docker file

```
FROM library/postgres:9.6
ADD init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

Comment: Вообще вся это фигня с регулярно неработающим приложением началась после обновления Мака до версии 10.13(((( И теперь эти баги постоянно прилетают(((

Comment: проверьте есть ли процесс с вашим приложением, и проверьте проброшен ли порт, `docker ps`. И еще докер не работает не на каком порту это виртуальное окружение для контейнеризации вашего приложения

Comment: @GVArt дополнила вопрос, очень прошу помогите, почему вообще все полетело после обновления?Вчера такая же фигня была, решили как-то в настройках поправив разрешение от Oracle, а сегодня в настройках нет этой опции вообще, я думаю может еще какое-то разрешение нужно?

Comment: @GVArt когда пытаюсь зайти на swagger, то выдает Unable to infer base url. This is common when using dynamic servlet registration or when the API is behind an API Gateway. The base url is the root of where all the swagger resources are served. For e.g. if the api is available at http://example.org/api/v2/api-docs then the base url is http://example.org/api/. Please enter the location manually: но вручную заполнение адреса ничего не дает

Comment: Вот тут ваша проблема https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1996, должно помочь

Comment: @GVArt именно это я и сделала - не помогло(((

Comment: именно добавили в игнор ` "/swagger-resources/**",
            "/swagger-ui.html",
            "/v2/api-docs",
            "/webjars/**"` ?

Comment: @GVArt da, imenno eto

Comment: Пожалуйста, кто-нибудь знает, как решить проблему? Я думаю, не может это быть связано с Томкатом? В смысле, может надо что-то исправить в server.xml? Сейчас там <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443"/>

Comment: @Mircella подключитесь к контейнеру, вызовите `curl localhost:8080` и посмотрите какой ответ возвращается

Comment: @SeniorPomidor ничего не возвращает, и если просто к localhost:8080 попробовать то дает This page isn’t working
localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE Хотя в Intellij отчетливо написано что Томкат стартанул на 8080, пытаюсь хоть к одному контроллеру обратиться - тишина, даже не попадаю на него

Comment: @Mircella приложите к вопросу как вы собираете и стартуете контейнер

Comment: @SeniorPomidor добавила в вопрос

Comment: @Mircella соберите просто `jar` файл и попробуйте запустить приложения через `java -jar` и посотрите работает ли оно. Если нет значит надо искать в направления сборки `jar` исли же да, то проблема в докере